# How do lattice-based proofs with Reed-Solomon codes simultaneously avoid aborts and multiple repeats?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, lattice-crypto

I'm trying to understand how lattice-based schemes with the Reed-Solomon proximity testing work and why the scheme in  [Bootle's et. al. Fig 3](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1449.pdf) has no aborts at all (nor big number of repetitions).

**TLDR**: How do PCPs and Reed-Solomon allow to avoid aborts and multiple repeats in Bootle's et. al. exact proof? I see no aborts and the challenge space is not a bit string either. Plus, they require just two repeats. So how does it work?

---

In classical crypto, say based on the DDH hardness assumption, we work with rings (or fields - depends). In lattices, we deal with **subset** of a ring (we need only those elements of the ring that have a small norm). So, all problems with "just using classical crypto tricks" boil down to the fact that this subset is not closed under addition or multiplication.

If we do crypto using the classical approach and big challenges, we *will leak the secret* with some probability (if the resulting element would not have a small norm). Ok for one-time signatures, bad for public key crypto. Sure, one can use a bit as a challenge and get Stern-type proofs, but it requires lots of repeats.

Then the concept of aborts appeared. If the resulting element had a big norm and could leak the secret - abort and restart protocol.

It all makes sense. We keep our subring but sometimes have to do the re-runs. We can try to increase the distribution of the masking parameter, do a parallel repetition, etc. But the core concept remains: our ring is not complete, and sometimes we hit a bad element and are forced to restart.

However, I do not understand how Bootle et. al manage to avoid aborts in their scheme. Do they use some Stern-like approach, which does not result in hundreds of re-runs? Is it because they work with many LWE instances, and big elements are somehow masked? Are Reed-Solomon codes somehow turning lattice subring into a closed ring?

Comment: Is it specifically appendix A you are asking about

Comment: @kodlu's comment on the appendix is helpful. Using RS encoding and committing codewords via a merkle tree is used to test linear relations with zero knowledge. The same technique can be used to prove arithmetic circuit satisfiability so it is somewhat problem independent.

Comment: @kodlu, thanks, skipped it when reading.

Comment: @Lev, so basically, instead of outputting an element of a subset as a result (sigma-proof style), we prove that a linear relation holds over encodings. And because the result is in the form Am + Br, there is no danger in revealing elements with a big norm. More or less?

Comment: I find it helpful to consider these RS IOPs as black boxes. They provide a way to prove some relation is zero knowledge. I'm not familiar with this specialized approach but I'd say yes, more or less.

Comment: @Lev, thank you!